# C to NASM conversion

Tags: c, bash, assembly, nasm

I'm trying to find a way to convert simple C code to NASM assembly. I have tried using objconv and downloaded and unzipped and built it since I am using a MAC; however, it doesn't seem to be working. I keep getting "-bash: objconv: command not found". Does anyone know another way or can help me solve the -bash error.

Comment: Some C compilers have an option to output assembly code.

Comment: until you understand how to permanently add elems to your PATH, just use `/full/path/to/bindir/objconv file`. The you may get messages like "`can't find libc.so"` (or `lsomething.a` and similar). Then you have to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH to include path to those library files. Post a new question on how to fix LD_LIBRARY_PATH. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

Bash is the program that takes the words you type in a terminal and launches other programs.  If it is reporting an error, it is because it cannot find the program you want to run (at least in this case).

You need to either find a pre-packaged installation of objconv, or you need to do the work to "integrate" your copy of objconv yourself.

If you can identify the executable you want to run (probably called objconv) you need to add that to your path.  The easiest way (if it is just for you) is to verify that your ~/.bashrc or ~/.bashprofile has a line that looks something like

```
PATH=$PATH:${HOME}/bin
```

Don't worry if it doesn't look exactly the same.  Just make sure there's a ${HOME}/bin or ~/bin (~ is the short version of ${HOME}).

If you have that then type the commands

```
cd ~/bin
ln -fs ../path/to/objconv
```

and you will create a soft link (a type of file) in your home binary directory, and the program should be available to the command line.

If you create the file, and nothing above has any errors, but it is not available to the command line, you might need to set the executable bit on your "real" (not link) copy of objconv.

If this doesn't work, by now you should be well primed for a better, more specific question.

Answer (score 2):

If you have gcc installed, try `gcc -masm=intel -S source.c` to generate assembly files in a syntax very similar to that of MASM.